# Could not find function or function reference 'ta.adx'

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Can anyone guide me with this error:

```
// ADX and ATR Calculation
adx = ta.adx(adxLength)  // Average Directional Index 
atr = ta.atr(atrLength)  // Average True Range
```

> Error at 19:7 Could not find function or function reference 'ta.adx'